# CORS issue in HERE map Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, heremaps

Hi I am trying to use HERE map in my ionic application .. I followed this blog
https://developer.here.com/blog/display-an-interactive-here-map-in-an-ionic-framework-application

I have created HERE account and get javascrio APPID and APIKEY from there and used in my code just like this ..

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var H: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild("map", {static: false})
    public mapElement: ElementRef;

    public constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit() { }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        let platform = new H.service.Platform({
            "app_id": 'XXXXXXX',
            "app_code": 'XXXXXXX' 
        });
        let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
        let map = new H.Map(
            this.mapElement.nativeElement,
            defaultLayers.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: { lat: '22.258651999999998', lng: '71.1923805' }
            }
        );
        let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
    }

}
```

My home.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <div id="container">
    <div #map style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

But I am getting there error when I run the project on browser..

[image]

Comment: Could you check this https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/http-request-headers.html

Comment: as I you can see I am not calling any HTTP methods I don't know how this is usefull for me .. can you please explain ?

Comment: Can you push your code to GitHub, so that I can look into it

Comment: yeah sure I can let me share repo here

Comment: just create blank ionic project and paste my code in that simple @PavanKumarJorrigala

Comment: ok I will try to do that

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you shared uses older version of HERE Javascript API (3.0).
Can you try with latest version 3.1?

Just replace `https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/..` with `https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/..`

Also with 3.1 version you should use `apikey` instead of `app_id`, `app_code` and also defaultLayers structure changed a bit:

```
let platform = new H.service.Platform({
    apikey: 'XXXXXXX'
});
let defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
let map = new H.Map(
    this.mapElement.nativeElement,
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
    {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: '22.258651999999998', lng: '71.1923805' }
    }
);
```

[Here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js) you can find live examples for HERE maps for JavaScript API.

Comment: ok the error is gone now but map is not showing do I need to do any other config ?

Comment: I have check div element something is added but still now able to show map on screen can you help @Tomas

Comment: @Kishan, are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YL1Rw412Tvw7wissiIZY2IfslN0Sq0Xs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check this image @Tomas

Comment: I see. Would be great if you could share your application too. Otherwise it's very difficult to debug.